# Office 2013 Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, ribbon-control, office-2013

I need to disable the File Ribbon options on word in office 2013. We have a template that uses VBA to create the document and it also creates custom add ins that we want our users to use not the file options.

Ideally within the VBA code we would set up the xml strings and use that to disable the File Ribbon. This way all docs created from this template would be identical. In my investigation I did come across the CustomUIEditor.exe that allows you to do this with already created documents.

Thanking in advance for any help

Comment: Instead of changing important Ribbon options (which I consider really bad practice) I would suggest to try to catch and change `NewDocument Event`. Some additional information regarding this event you can find  [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff836563%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the tip I will look into it. The client wants the file ribbon options disabled if a doc it created using there .dot template. I am out of my debt as I've never looked at this before so it is all new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the prev question I know there are other ways to do this but this is the most straight forward for the users I have.

If you want to disable the Ribbon just using VBA this is not possible, see:

[Updating Earlier Code for CommandBars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865324.aspx)

I know that you can use Dev Studio or a CustomUIEditor.exe editor to create your own XML and then convert a macro to a sub that catches the linked event. But I had various degrees of success but not enough that I was happy with it.

Instead I kept it simple ...  so that another developer at the office can quickly modify it with the default office 2013 tools.

I created a custom Ribbon, Created new buttons and then had them link to the macros I wanted. I then exported the custom ribbon for deployment to the users machines. I converted the old macro code to remove any depreciated code from 2003/ 2007 and created a new .dotm file and put the code within that. Our docs use that template to create the .doc files

Hope this helps. Please leave any comments on work arounds you may of done.